# Studio 3T Shell Presentation

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I installed Studio 3T and I chose GUI presentation, but I don't like it and I want to try shell one, but don't find a way to change it. Anyone knows how ?

Thanks

Comment: try `mongosh` for the mongoshell, or try mongodb compass you might like it(compass has shell also inside)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Preferences, select the General tab and change the "Default view when opening a collection" from "Collections/View Tab" to "IntelliShell" - Ok that and you'll get the shell experience.

Dj

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I Wanted 

Comment: what if i dont want the intellishell? i am unable to edit the default view.

Comment: @motionless570 - Are you on Studio 3T Free? That only has IntelliShell as an option.  Other default views are only available in the Basic, Pro and Ultimate versions.